# Silex REST login - How does it work?

Tags: rest, symfony, angularjs, silex

I'm using Silex for the backend of an angularjs app. I wanna realize an user-authentication. I used this tutorial (http://www.bubblecode.net/en/2012/08/28/mysql-authentication-in-silex-the-php-micro-framework/) and the official documentation to realize it so far. The backend returns pure JSON, no HTML.

My questions:

- How do I have to send the login-request? I never get an appropriated 
  response, just a 301 redirect. It's the same reponse like I get if I 
  try to access a ressource I don't have access.
- The backend always redirects me to the the login route if I don't have access to a page. All I want is an 401. How can I change this behaviour?

Thanks guys! Cheers Chris

Comment: Thanks mpm! Sure, the login should be a part of the angular app, but that's not the point of my question. I wanna have a rest-interface. My question how the post has to look, I send to the generated login_check-method?

Answer (score 1):

The call needs to send the parameters _username and _password to the check url.

This is taken from official documentation which can be found [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html):

> The form has very few requirements. First, by submitting the form to
>   /login_check (via the login_check route), the security system will
>   intercept the form submission and process the form for you
>   automatically. Second, the security system expects the submitted
>   fields to be called _username and _password (these field names can be
>   configured).

For your second question:
You can specifiy a redirect route as described [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/form_login.html). 
Then just return 401 as response for this route.

I hope this will help you.
Sorry for my bad english!